# How do I save an image file as a link in Python

Tags: python

I'm creating a project in face-clustering, and I cluster each image to the appropriate folder.
I wanna save memory space, so I dont want to "copy" the image But put a link in the appropriate folder for the image.
that what I did:

```
    # take the originial name of file
    filename = (data[i]["imagePath"].split('/'))[-1]

    # Using cv2.imwrite() method 
    # Saving the image 
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path , filename), file_)
```

I would happy to know how to create links instead of copy.
Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply writing the image path to a text file?

Comment: I don't want to create files from any type, I want to make like a list with links

Comment: What OS do you use please?

Comment: I uses the linux os

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a link for the file, have you tried using symlink? The documentation for symlink is as follows:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_symlink.htm

```
import os
destPath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "label")
if not os.path.exists(destPath):
    os.mkdir(destPath)

filePath = os.path.join(destPath, str(1)+".txt")
os.symlink("urls.txt", filePath)
```

Does this give an error too? Here I have used a sample text file "urls.txt" which you can try replacing with the image name.
Note: I think you must run an editor in administrator mode to have privilege to create symlinks.

If you want to create a file with list of the links such that clicking on it will open the image, is creating an HTML file with anchor tags and "href" with the file links an option?

Example:

```
<a href="/some/file/path.png" target="_blank">Filename</a>
```

P.S: Thanks Julien for the comment. Will keep that in mind.

Comment: I think its good, its seem exactly what I need,
but it gives me an error: FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists:   despite the file is exists

Comment: Hello @Etty Can you please paste the code you have written which gives this error?

Comment: os.symlink(data[i]["imagePath"], path)  path = os.getcwd()++'/label'+str(labelID) and if that destinitaion directory doesnt exist: I run: os.mkdir(path)  the source ia the path of the image

Comment: and I dont wanna do it with HTML maybe create a CSV file

Comment: That will be a pretty efficient option if you do not need to view the images once you save the links.

Comment: if I make a csv file with the pathes, how can I do it links and not just plain text?

Comment: I am not sure you can do links with CSV. If the links point to a file in the web and not your local machine, it might work for some software which reads CSV file (like Excel) but if the link points to a file in your local machine, it might not work as a link.